# Update specific row react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am new with react-native and what I am trying to achieve is in one Scroll View I have returned many Views and Texts and now lets say that I want to update on click specific row in this list, so first step is how to find that row with id or any other method and then how I can update value of that.

Comment: Please, create [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

the way you are trying to achieve is impossible(as far as I know).
How ever you can create a data array and use arra.map function this way you will be able to detect through your data where the user has tapped